# Cypress testing error, webpack related. Not sure on where to start with this one

Tags: javascript, npm, cypress

[image: Error on cypress UI]

Hello I am getting this error when I try to run a test file that I created. The default tests run fine. It is only the file that I created that causes this error

```
import {cypress as cy} from "cypress"

describe('Testing form inputs', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
    })
  });

 
    describe('My First Test', () => {
      it('Does not do much!', () => {
        expect(true).to.equal(true);
      })
    });

      describe('My New Test' , function () {
        
        it('Visits index site', function (){
          cy.visit("index.html");
        })
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to run again without `import {cypress as cy} from "cypress"`
[image: Execution]